# Find the MLE for $θ$

Tags: statistics

[Find the MLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpDIJ.png)

So for this question how would you go about finding the MLE?
because finding the derivative of the log likelihood gives you a zero.
How would I go about solving this question?

Comment: What is the maximal $\theta$ such that $X_i\ge \theta$ for all $i=1,\dots, n$?

Comment: would that just be the min Xi?